# Firebase action-hosting-deploy fails with RequestError (Resource not accessible by integration)

Tags: firebase, github-actions, firebase-hosting

Firebase action-hosting-deploy fails with RequestError (Resource not accessible by integration)

I am trying to follow https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/github-integration to start automatically pushing my code to be hosted by Firebase.

I've ended up with a Github Actions .yml file that looks like this:

```
# This file was auto-generated by the Firebase CLI
# https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on PR
'on': pull_request
jobs:
  build_and_preview:
    if: '${{ github.event.pull_request.head.repo.full_name == github.repository }}'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: development
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18'
      - run: |
          cd front
          echo "$ENV_DEVELOPMENT" > .env.development
          PWD=$(pwd)
          npm install
          sh -ac ". $PWD/.env.development; npm run build"
        env:
          ENV_DEVELOPMENT: ${{ secrets.ENV_DEVELOPMENT }}
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_MYPROJECT }}'
          projectId: myproject
```

It runs well until the last dash, i.e. `uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0`.

I get this error:

```
Run FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
/home/runner/work/_actions/FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy/v0/bin/action.min.js:3759
                const error = new RequestError(message, status, ***
                              ^

RequestError [HttpError]: Resource not accessible by integration
    at /home/runner/work/_actions/FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy/v0/bin/action.min.js:3759:31
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async createCheck (/home/runner/work/_actions/FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy/v0/bin/action.min.js:5680:17)
    at async run (/home/runner/work/_actions/FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy/v0/bin/action.min.js:11435:14) ***
  status: 403,
  headers: ***
    'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
    ...
    'x-xss-protection': '0'
  ***,
  request: ***
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/mygithubuser/myproject/check-runs',
    headers: ***
      accept: 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
      'user-agent': 'octokit-core.js/3.2.4 Node.js/16.16.0 (linux; x64)',
      authorization: 'token [REDACTED]',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    ***,
    body: '***"name":"Deploy Preview","head_sha":"27df35c365f7289ac219329aeb45824ac2fde64a","status":"in_progress"***',
    request: ***
      agent: Agent ***
        _events: [Object: null prototype] ***
          free: [Function (anonymous)],
          newListener: [Function: maybeEnableKeylog]
        ***,
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        default port: 443,
        ...
        maxCachedSessions: 100,
        _sessionCache: ***
          map: ***
            'api.github.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::': [Buffer [Uint8Array]]
          ***,
          list: [ 'api.github.com:443:::::::::::::::::::::' ]
        ***,
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
      ***,
      hook: [Function: bound bound register]
    ***
  ***,
  documentation_url: 'https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/checks#create-a-check-run'
***
```

At first, I thought this is a permissions error on my cloud service worker, but if I go in my console.cloud.google.com to IAM, I can see a github-action with the roles 'API Keys Viewer, Cloud Run Viewer, Firebase Authentication Admin and Firebase Hosting Admin'. To see if makes a difference, I also added the Owner role.

Any other suggestions I could try?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I ran into this error as well, so what i did to resolve the issue are:

1. On you your github repo click settings
2. Click actions and then General
3. Look for Workflow Permission section
4. choose the first option 'Read and write permission' and then the checkbox 'Allow GitHub Actions to create and approve pull requests'
   Please see attached file for your reference

[image]

Let me know if that resolves your problem as well.

Comment: That did fix. Thanks. Also curious why it needs write permission apart from read? If you are also aware of?

Comment: @Xin, Because its needs to deploy a copy of your PR  on your firebase hosting,  so the github token needs to have write permission

Comment: if the repository is part of an organisation, you have to set this on the organisation level.  repos can be more restrictive than the org, but not less.  (same for enterprises)

Comment: fix: in the repo in your github click settings on the left side of topbar, then you will winf actions/general on the left sidebar. (I have looked for it for 15 minutes..) :)

Comment: Am I missing something? This doesn't make sense. The deployment is on firebase, so that's the token that needs to have write permissions, not github's.

Comment: This helped me fix my issues. Works fine now.

Comment: @gustavohenke token on github can have permissions, in this case the token is used for firebase which needs a permission for your repo to read  and write to achived the deployment process

Answer (score 10):

try this: make sure to enable read and write permission for GITHUB_TOKEN. to do this, click on your github org (not repo), settings, actions, general, scroll down to Workflow permissions

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add that choosing just the first option "read and write permissions" without checking the checkbox for "Allow GitHub Actions to create and approve pull requests" worked for me as well.

If the repo belongs to an org you'll have to change the same Workflow Permissions in your Org's action settings as well.

Answer (score 2):

On top of what has previously been said by @drustan, to make it work you have to include this at the top-level of your yaml file:

```yaml
permissions:
  checks: write
  contents: read
  pull-requests: write
```

Hope this helps.